# What is the difference between $\ell^2(\mathbb{N})$ and $\ell^2(\mathbb{Z})$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, notation

What is the difference between $\ell^2(\mathbb{N})$ and $\ell^2(\mathbb{Z})$?

Is the difference just in the index, as follows?

$$ \ell^2(\mathbb{N}):=\big\{ (a_n)_{n\in \mathbb{N}} \mid a_n \in \mathbb{C}, \sum_{n\in\mathbb{N}} |a_n|^2 < \infty \big\}$$

$$ \ell^2(\mathbb{Z}) := \big\{ (a_n)_{n\in \mathbb{Z}} \mid a_n \in \mathbb{C}, \sum_{n\in\mathbb{Z}} |a_n|^2 < \infty \big\}$$

Comment: Yes, and they are isomorphic Hilbert spaces.

Comment: All separable infinite dimensional Hilbert spaces are isometrically isomorhpic.

Comment: Yes, the difference is just the index set.  Any bijection $\mathbb N \to \mathbb Z$ gives us an isometry between the spaces $\ell^2(\mathbb{N})$ and $\ell^2(\mathbb{\mathbb Z})$.  A reason to mention $\ell^2(\mathbb{\mathbb Z})$ would be when we have an orthonormal basis in some Hilbert space that is naturally indexed by $\mathbb Z$.  For example: $f_n(t) = e^{i 2 \pi n t}$ in $L^2[0,1]$.